# How to handle nested relationships in marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have a project where I'm trying to load data from JSON into a Sqlalchemy database using the marshmallow-sqlalchemy package.  The model contains a one-to-many relationship with a child model.

Using the classic example of an author with many books:

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(50))

    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("author.id"), nullable=False)
    author = relationship("Author", backref=backref("books"))


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "author"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250))

    books = relationship("Author", back_populates="author")


class BookSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        sqla_session = Session


class AuthorSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        sqla_session = Session

    books = fields.Nested(BookSchema, many=True)
```

And the input JSON is

```
{
    "name": "Author A",
    "books": [
        {"title": "Book 1"},
        {"title": "Book 2"}
    ]
 }
```

When I try to load that JSON, using the following:

```
json_repr = {...}
author_schema = AuthorSchema()
obj_repr = author_schema.load(json_repr)
```

It is raising an exception when it trys to deserialize the document saying that Book is an unhashable type.

What is happening, I believe is that the deserializer is trying to create the objects using something like

```
obj = model(**data)
```

which won't work with a one-to-many relationship, since the instances of the list need to be `append()`'ed to the Author.books property.

I've been unable to find any examples of this working anywhere on the web, Every example I've seen seems to be nesting a single instance, not a list.  Is there a recommended way of accomplishing this using marshmallow-sqlalchemy, or should I revert back to using the straight marshmallow package, and manually appending the relationship objects using @post_load methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having similar issues to this old post. Managed to fix this post under a slightly different framework Flask + SQLAlchemy + Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy (version 2). Posted code in case helpful.

Most of change are to `models.py`

1. Change of line `books = relationship("Book", back_populates="author")`
2. Used `back_populates` instead of `backref` as I was getting error `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'books' on relationship 'Book.author': property of that name exists on mapper 'mapped class Author->author`

models.py

```
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "book"
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(db.String(50))

    author_id = Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("author.id"), nullable=False)
    author = relationship("Author", back_populates="books")


class Author(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "author"
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(db.String(250))

    books = relationship("Book", back_populates="author")
```

schemas.py - mostly same

```
class BookSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        sqla_session = db.session


class AuthorSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        sqla_session = db.session

    books = fields.Nested(BookSchema, many=True)
```

views.py

```
@api.route('/author/', methods=['POST'])
def new_author():
    schema = AuthorSchema()
    author = schema.load(request.get_json())
    db.session.add(author.data) # version 2 marshmallow
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({"success": True})
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears, that one way of handling this is to add an initializer on the sqlalchemy model, which explicitly appends to the collection

```
class Author(Model):
    __tablename__ = "author"

    def __init__(self, books=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Author, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        books = books or []
        for book in books:
            self.books.append(book)
```

Still curious though if there is a better solution out there.

Comment: Did you find any other ways of doing it?